# Python string / bytes encoding with non ascii characters

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

I need to write a very simple function that reads from a json file and writes some of the content back to csv file.
The trouble is that the input json file has weird encoding format, for example :

```
{
"content": "b\"Comment minimiser l'impact environnemental d\\xe8s la R&D des proc\\xe9d\\xe9s micro\\xe9lectroniques."
}
```

I would like to write back

```
Comment minimiser l'impact environnemental dès la R&D des procédés microélectroniques.
```

The first problem is the 'b' so the content should read as a byte array but it is read as a string.
The second one is how to replace the weird characters ?
Thank you

Comment: Did you generate the JSON?  It was generated incorrectly.  It would be better to fix the JSON at the source.

Comment: I can't regenerated the json part unfortunatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
json_file_path = 'your_json_file.json'

with open(json_file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as j:
    # Remove problematic "b\ character
    j = j.read().replace('\"b\\',"");
    # Process json
    contents = json.loads(j)

# Decode string to process correctly double backslashes
output = contents['content'].encode('utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')

print(output)
# Output
# Comment minimiser l'impact environnemental dès la R&D des procédés microélectroniques.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
The replace part works and and removes the "b\ part, but I still have the weird characters.
output = contents['content'].encode('utf-8').decode('unicode_escape') gives me this error :
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x92'
So I had to change it to 
content.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')
But the output is : 
Comment minimiser l'impact environnemental d\xe8s la R&D des proc\xe9d\xe9s micro\xe9lectroniques

Comment: @AudVid it seems you have some weird encoding in other lines of the file. Try using my updated answear. If you are generating the JSON yourself, make sure to encode it with utf-8 as well when writing it

Comment: It works ! Thank you a lot, I tried so many things but maybe not this combination.